# Solving the ordinary differential equation: $(1 + x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} + 4xy = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I tried using integrating factor but was stuck at the integration of $e^2x^2/(1+x^2)^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE Niang. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question more clear.

Comment: The standard solution of $y'+Py=Q$ first multiplies by $R:=\exp\int Pdx$ so $R'=RP$ and $(Ry)'=RQ$, so $y=R^{-1}\int RQ dx$ as per the answer of mrs.

Comment: I edited your question by simply surrounding your $\LaTeX$ with "\$" signs.  But now I wonder where $e^2x^2/(1 + x^2)^2$ comes from?  Cheers!

Comment: it is exponent(2x^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The integrating factor is $$\exp{\left(\int \frac{4x dx}{1+x^2}\right)}=(1+x^2)^2$$ Note that I assumed you wrote the ODE as its standard form with $1$ as the coefficient of $y'$.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was not making the coefficient of y' equals 1

Comment: yr welcome dear friend! I did nothing for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We transform the ODE $$a\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+b\cdot y=c$$
into:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+Py=Q$$
then the Integrating Factor is $e^{\int P\space dx}$

Here, we divide by $(1+x^2)$ so that $P=\frac{4x}{1+x^2}$ and $Q=(1+x^2)^{-3}$

Then the Integrating Factor is $$e^{\int{\frac{4x}{1+x^2}dx}}$$
Use the substitution $u=1+x^2 \to dx=\frac{du}{2x}$ to evaluate the integral.

Finally, the shortcut:
$$I y=\int{IQ \space dx}$$
(where $I$ is the Integrating Factor) will help you the rest of the way.